# SQLPlus INSERT INTO "(USER)"."USERS" (USER_NAME, USER_PASS) < "how to hash password"

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert

Good morning,

I'm certain this is a duplicate question but struggling to word this properly since I am not an SQL person, I've just been tasked with this.

I'm using ORACLE SQLPlus, in SQLDeveloper I have "Other Users" > SuperAdmin with a table below called USERS.

To add a new user to this database I'm using:

```
INSERT INTO "SUPERADMIN"."USERS" (USER_NAME, USER_PASS) VALUES ('SUPERTEST', 'NewPassword01')
```

It adds my user, but how do I hash out the plain text password?

Again, my sincerest apologies if this is a duplicate.

Comment: "how do I hash out the plain text password?" Which hash algorithm do you want to use? There are many and if you don't use the correct one for your application then when your application hashes the user input using a different hash algorithm then the values won't match.

Comment: If this is for an existing application, does it already have functionality to hash the password, and maybe create the user - perhaps in a package?

Comment: @MT0 SHA I believe. Based on the JAVA application someone has built to add users for me.

Comment: @AlexPoole The JAVA application works fine, but the task I've been given is to automate the whole process, so I'm building a .sql file for injection and can't use the app.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your `USER_PASS` column has a `RAW` data type then use the [`STANDARD_HASH` function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/STANDARD_HASH.html#GUID-4A68DACE-CFCF-443B-8651-B6CEAA7C4FD7):

```sql
INSERT INTO SUPERADMIN.USERS (
  USER_NAME,
  USER_PASS
) VALUES (
  'SUPERTEST',
  STANDARD_HASH( 'NewPassword01', 'SHA1' )
);
```

*(Valid hash algorithms for the second argument are: `SHA1`, `SHA256`, `SHA386`, `SHA512` or `MD5`.)*

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d381a06e2d8288422008f7f3c7ff65a2)*

---

## Update

> I've had a look at the settings, the `USER_PASS` is Simple `VARCHAR2`.

You should really work out how your current system is hashing the string and encoding it because if you don't do exactly the same method then things will go wrong.

You could use `UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2` if you want to convert the `RAW` value to a string without any encoding:

```sql
INSERT INTO USERS (
  USER_NAME,
  USER_PASS
) VALUES (
  'SUPERTEST',
  UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(
    STANDARD_HASH( 'NewPassword01', 'SHA1' )
  )
);
```

You could use `RAWTOHEX` to convert the `RAW` output if you want to encode it as a hexadecimal string:

```sql
INSERT INTO USERS (
  USER_NAME,
  USER_PASS
) VALUES (
  'SUPERTEST',
  RAWTOHEX( STANDARD_HASH( 'NewPassword01', 'SHA1' ) )
);
```

You could also use `UTL_ENCODE.BASE64_ENCODE` if you wanted the value in a Base64 encoding:

```sql
INSERT INTO USERS (
  USER_NAME,
  USER_PASS
) VALUES (
  'SUPERTEST',
  UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(
    UTL_ENCODE.BASE64_ENCODE(
      STANDARD_HASH( 'NewPassword01', 'SHA1' )
    )
  )
);
```

As you can see they all take the same input but they give very different values:

```sql
SELECT * FROM superadmin.users;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> USER_NAME | USER_PASS                               
> :-------- | :---------------------------------------
> SUPERTEST | %U)?Q0?????lR? xm/                     
> SUPERTEST | 255529AE5130DAB082A29CAC6C52BC20786D2F01
> SUPERTEST | JVUprlEw2rCCopysbFK8IHhtLwE=
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=84c15032b757abc6fddff8d83b37f4f8)*

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I'm guessing mine does not have a RAW data type as I get SQL Error: ORA-00904: "STANDARD_HASH": invalid identifier 00904. 

Using SQL Developer I've had a look at the settings, the USER_PASS is Simple VARCHAR2. Units BYTE

Comment: @GrahamJordan Updated the answer to convert the `RAW` to a string .... however, you should work out how your current system works and then come back and ask a more targetted question because all we're doing is guessing as to how it works and if your method isn't the same then an output we suggest won't match what your application expects.

Comment: Thank you so much for all the time you've put into this, truly I am grateful. I think I may have found the reason why STANDARD_HASH is refusing to work. I'm using Oracle 11.2. and by the looks of things, STANDARD_HASH was added on the next release. 
https://docs.oracle.com/apps/search/search.jsp?word=password&product=e11882-01&book=e41084. Having a look myself now for clues, now I have a starting point.